# Select all features close to clicked

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector

I have an openlayers map with more then 20000 features not in wms, only in vector layer. I have a control to select features, but sometimes it's really hard to select, specially the lines, and also the other feature because they are too close. So instead the regular select tool I want to be able to click on the map, and get all the close features then chose what to select. How I wanted to do it it's like this: when I click it's create a little circle and I check all the features that in the circle (even little part from the feature) I didn't really find a function to do it in the api, it's possible to do it? Or someone have other solution? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use the box selection method used at http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/select-feature.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/XfEmn/

1. detect the point clicked
2. find the feature closest to this point
3. use the selectFeatureControl to programatically select this feature